# mysql - Can  a join query do the same tasks to one query

Tags: mysql

```
Table A
Table B
Tabls C1, C2 .... Cn : title field

relationship C INNER JOIN B LEFT JOIN A

query 
SELECT C1.title FORM C1 
INNER JOIN B on C1.c_id = B.c_id
LEFT JOIN A on B.b_id = A.b_id
```

Can it be merged into one query ?

Comment: Looks like one query to me also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but if `C1`, `C2`, ..., `Cn` are all "parallel" tables, then perhaps a UNION does the trick:

```
SELECT C1.title AS title FROM C1 INNER JOIN B on C1.c_id = B.c_id LEFT JOIN A on B.b_id = A.b_id
UNION ALL
SELECT C2.title AS title FROM C2 INNER JOIN B on C2.c_id = B.c_id LEFT JOIN A on B.b_id = A.b_id
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT Cn.title AS title FROM Cn INNER JOIN B on Cn.c_id = B.c_id LEFT JOIN A on B.b_id = A.b_id
```

Comment: thanks ! i will try it, maybe it's what i need